# Access XAML controls from C# code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml

I have two files in my VS project: `Custom.xaml` and `Custom.cs`

In my *XAML* file, I have the following text boxes:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Black" Background="Green" SelectionChanged="TextBox1_SelectionChanged" />

<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Black" Background="Green" SelectionChanged="TextBox2_SelectionChanged" />
```

In my *.cs*, I have the following method:

```
 void TextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox t = e.Source as TextBox
 }
```

I can successfully hit the event handler above. Then, I can grab `TextBox1` and it's properties by using `e.Source`, but I would like to access TextBox2 and it's properties.

As a sidenote, the *.cs* file is just a `C#` class that I am referencing, not a *xaml.cs*. Additionally, I understand that I could implement this via a *UserControl*, but cannot do that in this scenario for reasons that are outside the scope of this post.

Please advise on how I can get/set properties of `TextBox2`.

Thanks.

EDIT: Any other input on this? As a workaround, I've added an event handler called TextBox2_Loaded, and then set e.Source to an instance variable. Then, in TextBox1_SelectionChanged, I can access the instance variable. Would really like to just target the control directly (ex. TextBox2.IsEnabled). I must be missing a declaration or inheritance somewhere. Can't even find the control using FindName.

Comment: are u using the textbox2 as an item of a repeating control (a gridview,   listview..etc)?

Comment: No, I am not using a gridview or listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so I apparently had left out a critical component in this post... My TextBox controls are inside of DataTemplate controls. From my research, the TextBox controls cannot be accessed when inside of DataTemplate controls. I really didn't think that would matter, but I guess the instance variables are not created when this scenario exists.

If I've interpreted this incorrectly, please provide input. For now, I've gone ahead and added a Loaded event and defined my TextBox controls as instance variables so that I can access them and change properties when other activities occur.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: Of course, you cannot access a named component from a DataTemplate, even in a loaded event.
You need to catch the instance of your cerated UI Component.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have set a namein the XAML, you can access it directly by name (The XAML compiler will create an instance variable for you.)

```
void TextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    TextBox t = e.Source as TextBox 
    TextBox2.Text = "Whatever";
}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't use TextBox2 though. Intellisense doesn't display it and the compiler thinks it is undefined. Do I need to inherit my class from something? public partial class Custom : ?

Comment: Try doing a build so that Studio can see the fields that the xaml compiler will create. EDIT. Yes, your code behind should be a partial class that matches your XAML.

Comment: Are you confirming that my definition of my class is correct or that I need to be inheriting from something? Also, I have built my project several times.

Comment: I've also thought about just defining the controls on the _Loaded event. Thoughts? I'm trying to implement this now.

Comment: I dont know how this is supposed to work, as TextBox2 is just the typename and not a defined variable. Instead you should write 't.Text = "Whatever"

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me. I had to close my solution and reopen it.